# Use multiple csv files as test and training set for CNN

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am writing a code to detect minerals from their Raman Spectra data using CNN. I have data (RRUFF dataset) for different minerals written into different csv/text files each consisting of 2 columns: Intensity and corresponding Raman Shift value of the mineral.

How should I use these multiple files for training and testing my CNN?
Can I use flow_from_directory directly for csv files under Train and Test folders?

Total csv/txt files in dataset: 3696

Comment: If the CSV's features are all the same (Columns match) then I'd suggest load a dataset into pandas DataFrame and append each subsequent csv that you have. Afterwards, split the dataset by the 80:20 rule for 80% training and 20% testing. You can also do a 60-20-20 for Train/Test/Validate.

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_data(csv_files, columns, output_file):
    df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    for file in csv_files:
        df = df.append(pandas.read_csv(file), sort=False)
    return df
```

Now,  call the function `df = merge_data(['file1.csv', file2.csv], ['column1', 'column2'], 'all_data.csv')`

Then, split the merged data into train and test set using `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection`